# bash script loop until webserver response 200

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, httpd

I'm struggling to create a bash script that monitors the web service and if is down to restart the service in a while loop until it comes back up with a 200 status response.

Example :

```
#!/bin/bash
HTTPD=`curl -A "Web Check" -sL --connect-timeout 3 -w "%{http_code}\n" "http://127.0.0.1" -o /dev/null`
until [ "$HTTPD" == "200" ]; do
    printf '.'
    sleep 5
    service nginx restart
done

or

while [ "$HTTPD" != "200" ];
do
   service nginx restart
   sleep 5
   if [ "$HTTPD" == "200" ];then
        break;
   else
        service nginx restart
   fi
done
```

Both of them are working like 80% , the problem is that the loop will not re-check the status of $HTTPD response and break the loop.

I could add HTTPD=200; after restart line , but I want the script to check for the real status response.

**EDIT:** Working version

```
#!/bin/bash

HTTPD=`curl -A "Web Check" -sL --connect-timeout 3 -w "%{http_code}\n" "http://127.0.0.1" -o /dev/null`
until [ "$HTTPD" == "200" ]; do
    printf '.'
    sleep 3
    service nginx restart
    HTTPD=`curl -A "Web Check" -sL --connect-timeout 3 -w "%{http_code}\n" "http://127.0.0.1" -o /dev/null`
done
```

Comment: I don't know why this question is down-voted multiple times, but I want to say thank you for providing the EDIT: Working version -- it helped me. I hope you have a great day. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Plenty of tools do this already. Also, you check the status of the web server exactly once at the startup of the script (the `curl` command doesn't get executed every time you reference the $HTTP variable, but only once when you initially define the variable. You would need to add the `HTTP=\`curl` line into the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Even in the edit you're checking for a condition in the outermost loop. Once that condition is satisfied that loop exits.

Your description sounds like you're trying to do

```
while true
do
  HTTPD=`curl -A "Web Check" -sL --connect-timeout 3 -w "%{http_code}\n" "http://127.0.0.1" -o /dev/null`
  until [ "$HTTPD" == "200" ]; do
    printf '.'
    sleep 3
    service nginx restart
    HTTPD=`curl -A "Web Check" -sL --connect-timeout 3 -w "%{http_code}\n" "http://127.0.0.1" -o /dev/null`
  done
  sleep 5
done
```

The outermost `while true` is an infinite loop that will only exit when you kill the (checking) process